# How to solve Intervals and sets

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

Let the universal set be the set $\Bbb{R}$ of all real numbers and let
$A = \{x \in \Bbb{R}\mid 0 < x \le 2\}$, $B = \{ x \in \Bbb{R}\mid 1 \le x < 4\}$ and $C = \{ x \in \Bbb{R}\mid 3 \le x < 9\}$.
Construct the set, $A - B^c$

I have drawn a number line taking min and max values, so, $0$ as min and $4$ as max

Line A, I had a hollow dot at $0$ and solid dot at $4$
Line B, Solid dot at $1$ and hollow dot at $4$

I thought the range of the complement of $B$ would be $x$ greater than or equal to $4$ and less than or equal to $1$

That was wrong.

1. Does the range of the complement equal greater/less than or equal to if it is a hollow dot....and less/greater than if it a solid dot?
2. I get lost as to how to work out the final answer...i.e. construct the set

Answer (score 0):

Some corrections:

Since $$A = \{x \in \Bbb{R}\mid 0 < x \le 2\}$$

Line **segment** A, I had a hollow dot at $0$ and solid dot at $\color{red}2$

the range of the complement of $B$ would be ($x$ greater than or equal to 4)
**or** ( $x$ less than  1).

Hint:

Note that $A-B^c=A \cap (B^c)^c$